# echo if POST length is low

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if all `$_POST` lengths are over 4.

```
$valid = true;
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    if (strlen($val) < 4) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$valid) {
    echo "Proceed";
    // All $_POST are at least 4 characters long
} else {
    echo "Error"; // why won't this show?
}
```

All works but why doesn't `echo "Error"` work? SO basically I want to echo the `Error` if any of the `POST`'s length is below 4.

Comment: What do you mean "All POST lengths?"

Comment: thought you got your answer from last question o.O

Comment: you should be checking post values....? not the post itself.  See [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: I take it you are new :).... There is answers at the bottom I +1 few

Comment: your `else{...}` should go inside the same loop as your `if{...}` and getting rid of the other `if (!$valid)`

Comment: and your `$valid = false;` should be true, since if it validates, it's true and not false. There's no need for those other `if/else`, IMO. and using `if (strlen($val) <= 4)` being less than or equal to 4.

Comment: you're welcome. However, the answer you accepted; does it match what you wanted to achieve? not clear if my comment above was the clincher ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `(strlen($_POST) < 4)` to `(strlen($val) < 4)`. And you need to change `(!$valid)`to `($valid)`.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$val` when checking and reverse your `if`:

```
$valid = true;
foreach ($_POST as $name => $val) {
    if (strlen($val) < 4) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
if ($valid) {
    echo "Proceed";
    // All $_POST are at least 4 characters long
} else {
    echo "Error"; // why won't this show?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the if statement is wrong, it should be

```
if($valid)    { 
echo "Proceed";
} else {
echo "Error"
}
```

Comment: True... that is also wrong

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget $_POST is associative... So if you want to check the POST values....

```
foreach($_POST as $a => $b) {
   if(strlen($b) < 4) {
      $valid = false;
      break;
   }
}
```